# Camel - Spring Boot Security - REST - 404 on sending wrong credentials

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, apache-camel, basic-authentication, spring-security-rest

This is really a weird error. Am trying spring security on camel restlets endpoints

**Route**

```
from("restlet://test?restletMethod=GET").to("some endpoint");
```

**Added default Security jar**

```
spring-boot-starter-security
```

**Application.properties**

```
security.basic.enabled=true
security.user.name=user
```

**Context Configuration**

```
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        SpringServerServlet servlet = new SpringServerServlet();
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean( servlet , "/*");

        registration.setName("restlet");

        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("org.restlet.component", "restletComponent");

        registration.addInitParameter( "org.restlet.component", "restletComponent" );

        return registration;
    }
```

When the run the APP as spring boot application, it generates a default password.

```
Using default security password: f701928f-29c6-448f-9640-430cc5f215be
```

Now, if I call the rest using correct credentials, its working fine. But if I call with **wrong credentials** , it is returning **404 not found**

Whats wrong ?

Comment: So I have a couple of questions: 1) which version of spring boot are you using? 2) how is your authentication failure url configured? 3) have you configured an access denied handler error page 403? If not, this will automatically redirect to a 404 error.

Comment: 1) 1.5.7 2) No 3) No. But the example I got is working without configuring anything. It throws "Full Authentication Required" error clearly

Comment: Looks like the configuration i use is causing the problem. Updating the question. Still no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the ServletRegistrationBean am Using , which catches 401 error and sends redirect to a page called **/error.**

Unfortunately, there is not fix for this. But there is a work around.

Have a simple rest api called with path as '/error' and return any output you want.

Example

```
from("restlet:/error?restletMethods=GET").transform(simple("unauthorized"));
```